# Does NVidia GTX980 support 10 bit color depth for 10 bit monitors (i.e. Samsung ud590)?

Tags: display, resolution, adobe-photoshop, nvidia-graphics-card

My control panel shows that it is unavailable, but that may be due to my current monitor which has no 10-bit support. Were I to attach a supporting monitor (i.e. the example above UD590, supporting 10 bits), would GTX980 have 10 bit available and would it be evident in Adobe applications (PS/AE)?

Comment: Windows maxes out at 8-bits per channel anyway, so even if both your monitor and graphics card supported 10-bits per channel, Windows couldn't display it.

Comment: So OSX is the only way to have 10bits?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OSX. But if it supports 10-bit video, then I guess the answer is obvious. According to what I've read, the human eye can perceive a bit over 10,000,000 colors and 8-bit video can generate 16,000,000 colors, so 8-bit ought to be good enough. That said, I'm not sure I agree with the 10 million figure. I think it makes assumptions about human color perception that are based on false assumptions.